# R error: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib

Tags: r

R was working fine until the security app installed by my school run yesterday.   I am having this  issue, `Library not loaded:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib` in some but not all packages.

Here is my R installation;

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions ❯ l                                                                                                              02:53:02 PM
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  5 root  admin   160B May 20 13:04 .
drwxrwxr-x  8 root  admin   256B May 20 13:04 ..
drwxrwxr-x  5 root  admin   160B May 20 13:29 4.1
drwxrwxr-x  6 root  admin   192B May 20 13:04 4.2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin     3B May 20 13:03 Current -> 4.2
```

There is no lib/ in 4.1/Resources and a current version should be 4.2 but for some reasons, it looks for 4.1.

Interesting, if I run R from terminal but not Rstudio, everything works fine.

I'd appreciate any help to restore the libR.dylb path.

```
> Sys.getenv('R_HOME')
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6.5

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BiocGenerics_0.43.0

PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/CyberArk EPM.app/Contents/Helpers:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.LzOT3qwX1V/org.xquartz:0

neofetch                                                                                                                                              03:09:06 PM
                    'c.          
                 ,xNMM.          ---------------------------
               .OMMMMo           OS: macOS 11.6.5 20G527 x86_64
               OMMM0,            Host: Macmini8,1
     .;loddo:' loolloddol;.      Kernel: 20.6.0
   cKMMMMMMMMMMNWMMMMMMMMMM0:    Uptime: 2 hours, 44 mins
 .KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.    Packages: 120 (brew)
 XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX.      Shell: zsh 5.8
;MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM:       Resolution: 1920x1080
:MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM:       DE: Aqua
.MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX.      WM: Quartz Compositor
 kMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.    WM Theme: Blue (Light)
 .XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMk   Terminal: iTerm2
  .XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK.   Terminal Font: MesloLGS-NF-Regular 11
    kMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMd     CPU: Intel i7-8700B (12) @ 3.20GHz
     ;KMMMMMMMWXXWMMMMMMMk.      GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630
       .cooc,.    .,coo:.        Memory: 36150MiB / 65536MiB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a right fix but the way I did was as follows;

```
mv 4.1 4.1.old  
ln -s 4.2/ 4.1
```

This worked.  For some unknown reasons, only in Rstudio, the path to the current R version, 4.2 is not recognized.

Comment: Where do I run these commands?

Comment: Where, you mean like in the  terminal ?

Comment: Yes, in which directory?

Comment: Sorry, I was being silly! My problem is a bit different though.  Trying to open an R executable and it's looking for libR.dylib of R version 3.5 which isn't even installed on my machine anymore. But thanks!